# Flash Actionscript 3 - play animation in reverse

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two movieclips. when .left is hovered over the animation .box plays moving from right to left but stops when .left isn't hovered over.

i want the same to happen with .right but the animation .box plays in reverse. i can achieve all of this except i cant't get the animation to stop playing in reverse when .right isn't hovered over, it just continues until .box is at the start again.

eventually i want to turn this concept into scrolling for a horizontal website. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code i have so far...

```
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,left_scroll_over);
left.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,left_scroll_off);
right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,right_scroll_over);
right.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,right_scroll_off);

//scrolling left
function left_scroll_over(e:MouseEvent):void
{    
    box.play();
    right.visible = true;
}
function left_scroll_off(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    box.stop();
    if (box.currentFrame == 59)
    {
        left.visible = false;
        right.visible = true;
    } 
}


 // scrolling right
function right_scroll_off(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    box.stop();
}
function right_scroll_over(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse, false, 0, true);
}
function playReverse(e:Event):void
{
    if (box.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        stopPlayReverse();
        right.visible = false;
        left.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        box.prevFrame();
        left.visible = true;
    }
}
function stopPlayReverse():void
{
    if (this.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME))
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still relevant: How do you start to reverse the animation? Probably not with box.play(), so box.stop() won't work either.

If the animation is not too complicated, you may consider scripting it as a tween. That way you can define the direction of the animation as a variable.